# How to connect circles with lines using canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am using canvas tag to create circles on over world map image. I want to connect the multiple circles with lines using Canvas tag. As of Now I am able to draw circles but couldn't able to draw lines.

HTML

```
<img src="http://educypedia.karadimov.info/library/worldoutlinemap.gif" width="500"/>
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas3" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas4" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

CSS

```
#myCanvas1
{
  position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 245px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#myCanvas2
{
  position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 25px;
    z-index: 3;
}

#myCanvas3
{
  position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 60px;
    z-index: 3;
}

#myCanvas4
{
  position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 200px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Javascript

```
/* circle1 */
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 10;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'grey';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    /* circle1 */  

    /* circle2 */
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 10;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'grey';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    /* circle2 */

  /* circle3 */
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas3');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 10;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'grey';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    /* circle3 */

  /* circle4 */
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas4');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 10;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'grey';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    /* circle4 */
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0t0hLju1/2/)

Comment: you do know, that you can draw all 4 circles in one canvas? Then you can simply use the circles center-coordinates as source and origin for the lines.

Comment: thanks @ThomasAltmann

Answer (score 2):

Here's another implementation I wrote for a question some time back. The code draws lines from the outline of 1 circle to the outline of another circle. The code relies upon the principals of vectors and, to ensure the line is not drawn inside the circle, that of unit-vectors.

First, we determine the vector between the centre points of 2 circles. Next, we move 'radius' units towards the middle of the line from each circle. This has the effect of computing the intersection between the circle and the line. Finally, we draw from one modified end-point to the next.

If you run the code a few times, you'll get circles that overlap. You can clearly see that circle outlines are drawn, but not filled. If you need to fill the circles anyway, my code is overkill, since the portion of the line that extends inside the circle will be covered anyway. :)

```js
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e)}
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

var shapeList = [];

function onDocLoaded()
{
 var i, n=3;
 var canvas = byId('myCanvas');
 
 for (i=0; i<n; i++)
 {
  shapeList[i] = new circle_t(Math.random()*578, Math.random()*400, Math.random()*30 + 20);
  shapeList[i].draw(canvas);
 }
 
 for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
  draw_line2(shapeList[i].origX, shapeList[i].origY, shapeList[i].radius, shapeList[i+1].origX, shapeList[i+1].origY, shapeList[i+1].radius);
} 

var shape_t = function(x,y)
{
 this.origX = (x==undefined ? 0 : x);
 this.origY = (y==undefined ? 0 : y);
}
shape_t.prototype =
{
 origX:0, origY:0, typeString:'shape',
 setPos: function(x,y){this.x=x;this.y=y;},
 setType: function(typeString){this.typeString = typeString;},
 toString: function(){return this.typeString + " - " + this.origX + "," + this.origY;},
 draw: function(canElem){},
};

function circle_t(x,y,radius)
{
 this.origX = (x==undefined ? 0 : x);
 this.origY = (y==undefined ? 0 : y);
 this.radius = (radius==undefined ? 10 : radius);
 this.setType("circle");
}
circle_t.prototype = new shape_t();
circle_t.prototype.constructor = circle_t;
circle_t.prototype.draw = function(canElem, color)
{
 var ctx = canElem.getContext('2d');
 var col = 'black';
 if (color != undefined)
  col = color;
 drawCircle(this.origX, this.origY, this.radius, ctx, col);
}

circle_t.prototype.setRadius = function(radius)
{
 if (radius != undefined)
  this.radius = radius;
}

function drawCircle(x, y, radius, ctx, col)
{
 ctx.save();
 if (col == undefined)
  col = 'black';
 ctx.strokeStyle = col;
 ctx.lineWidth = 1;
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(x,y,radius,(Math.PI/180)*0, (Math.PI/180)*360, false);
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.restore();
}

// define a vec2 class to make vector maths easier (simpler to read)
function vec2(x,y)
{
 this.length = function()
 {
  return Math.sqrt((this.x * this.x) + (this.y*this.y));
 }
 this.normalize = function()
 {
  var scale = this.length();
  this.x /= scale;
  this.y /= scale;
 }
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
}

function draw_line2(center1_x, center1_y, radius1, center2_x, center2_y, radius2)
{
 var betweenVec = new vec2(center2_x - center1_x, center2_y - center1_y);
 betweenVec.normalize();
 
 var p1x = center1_x + (radius1 * betweenVec.x);
 var p1y = center1_y + (radius1 * betweenVec.y);
 
 var p2x = center2_x - (radius2 * betweenVec.x);
 var p2y = center2_y - (radius2 * betweenVec.y);

 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(p1x,p1y);
  context.lineTo(p2x,p2y);
 context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @enhzflep

Answer (score 0):

Check this working code:

HTML

```
<img src="http://educypedia.karadimov.info/library/worldoutlinemap.gif" width="500"/>
<canvas id="line" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas3" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas4" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

JS

```
/*line1*/
    var canvas = document.getElementById('line');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(130, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
  ctx.stroke();

/* circle1 */
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 10;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'grey';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    /* circle1 */  

    /* circle2 */
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 10;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'grey';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    /* circle2 */

  /* circle3 */
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas3');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 10;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'grey';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    /* circle3 */

  /* circle4 */
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas4');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 10;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'grey';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    /* circle4 */
```

CSS

```
#line
{
  position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
}

#myCanvas1
{
  position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 245px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#myCanvas2
{
  position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 25px;
    z-index: 3;
}

#myCanvas3
{
  position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 60px;
    z-index: 3;
}

#myCanvas4
{
  position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 200px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

This is also available [as a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0t0hLju1/3/).

Comment: Thanks @hirenJungi

Comment: happy coding :)

Comment: this is the fiddle if want to see it live. http://jsfiddle.net/0t0hLju1/3/

Comment: Thanks for the repair of the question, though please avoid using the quote device merely for decoration. Quote blocks are for quotes.